# eclipse で PHPのxdebugを動かせません

Tags: php, eclipse

macOS High Sierra上でeclipse4.7.2を使っています。PHPおよびxdebugはbrewでインストールしました。

php.iniに、

---

zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php72-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"

---

と記述し、
phpinfo()でxdebugの項目が表示されているのを確認しています。

ところがDebug as -> Debug on Serverを選択しても
ブレークポイントでプログラムが止まりません。

何か設定ミスなのでしょうか。

Comment: xdebug.remote_autostart=onを指定してやると、ブレークポイントで止まるようになりましたが、Debugではなく、runした場合にも、デバッグモードに入るようになりました。とりあえずデバッグできるようになりましたが、なんらかの設定で自動的に切り替えられればいいなと考えています。

Answer (score -1):

設定をいろいろ触っていたら、デバッグできるようになりました。
具体的にどこだという事はできないのですが。